# javascript selector visualizer. how to see what Jquery has found?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

i'm trying to understand how does following `any-attribute-selector` works...

```
$('td[abbr="Role"] >div')
```

the main question is: does this selector choose  dom element
and the second question is how selector recognize string after closing bracket

```
] >div'
```

and the last question is there any site like http://jsfiddle.net/ where i could see the element which was found by selector. in **jsfiddle.net** i guess i can't see and find and be sure that i've found the particular element. Because **jsfiddle** as any other browser just finds element behind the scenes.

Comment: "does this selector choose dom element" What do you mean? "how selector recognize string after closing bracket" It's called a selector parser.

Comment: Install firebug extension for firefox, and in your javascript do like this: `var items = $('td[abbr="Role"] > div"); console.log(items);`

Comment: you can try `$('td[abbr="Role"] >div').css('outline','green')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RaraituL recommends, use the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) extension for Firefox (or the Developer Tools integrated in Chrome; it is essentially an integrated Firebug) to get a working JS console; and then debug your expressions by writing

```
var result = $(my_selector); console.log(result);
```

in the console. The output will be something like

```
Object[match1, match2, match3]
```

and you will be able to click on each of these to see where it is in the page, and what are its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td[abbr="Role"] >div')
```

Selects all direct child `div` elements of the element `td` with `abbr` attribue equal to `Role`